# How to use ngIf on material input in a child component without getting ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

#### The problem

I have a `PasswordComponent` that I want to use `ng-template` in.  However, I'm now getting `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error when I'm editing the password.  I only want to use the `errorStateMatcher` when `controlName === 'confirmPassword'` and I couldn't figure another way to conditionally bind `errorMatcher`

The complete code can be seen [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tvwdqq?embed=1&file=src/app/password.component.html) and inside `password.component.html` you will find the `ng-template` that's causing the problem:

```html
  <template *ngIf="controlName === 'confirmPassword'; then Custom else Default"></template>
  <ng-template #Custom>
    <input matInput [placeholder]="placeholder" [formControlName]="controlName" [type]="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'" [autocomplete]="autocomplete" [errorStateMatcher]="errorMatcher"/>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #Default>
    <input matInput [placeholder]="placeholder" [formControlName]="controlName" [type]="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'" [autocomplete]="autocomplete"/>
  </ng-template>
```

> Note: Even if you remove the `ng-template` and put the `ngIf` on the `input` directly the error still shows.  I originally thought the problem to be with the `ng-template`, but it's actually the `ngIf`.

#### The Error

The `mat-error` numbers vary and sometimes the value is `aria-describedby: null`.

```
PasswordComponent.html:4 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'aria-describedby: mat-error-3'. Current value: 'aria-describedby: mat-error-4'.
```

#### Error Repro Steps

- Enter something in the password field
- Tab/click back to username
- Tab/click back to password
- Type or delete characters such that the `mat-error` message changes
- You will see a `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` in the console.

Comment: I found this https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7737 github issue.  Looks like the root problem is using `ngIf` with `input`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
  <input #Custom *ngIf="controlName === 'confirmPassword'; else Default" matInput [placeholder]="placeholder" [formControlName]="controlName" [type]="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'" [autocomplete]="autocomplete" [errorStateMatcher]="errorMatcher"/>

<ng-template #Default> 
        <input matInput [placeholder]="placeholder" [formControlName]="controlName" [type]="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'" [autocomplete]="autocomplete"/> 
    </ng-template>
```

**EDIT**

In a nutshell it's probably down to a child template using a parent value that has been modified after the child is rendered. This usually happens as the children are rendered before the parent is finished rendering. I initially thought it was down to the fact that you placed the errorStateMatcher directive in a child template.

Have a look at the following article as it explains the issue better than I can and also goes through some common patterns that cause the problem and how to change them to fix it:

https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

**EDIT**

Following on from your comments it might be that the ngIf directive is conflicting with the matInput directive. Can you try the following:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="controlName === 'confirmPassword'; else Default">
    <input #Custom matInput [placeholder]="placeholder" [formControlName]="controlName" [type]="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'" [autocomplete]="autocomplete" [errorStateMatcher]="errorMatcher"/>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #Default> 
    <input matInput [placeholder]="placeholder" [formControlName]="controlName" [type]="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'" [autocomplete]="autocomplete"/> 
</ng-template>
```

The following is a working example of this: [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8wvjnm?embed=1&file=app/input-error-state-matcher-example.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried your suggestion [here](https://angular-qklsww.stackblitz.io), but I still get the same error.  Any idea why using `ngIf` and/or `ng-template` breaks Angular's change detection?

Comment: Essentially it's a basic error in the sense that symptom is easy to see / discover however the underlying cause is not always easy to diagnose.

Comment: Actually, the problem is the `ngIf` and nothing in the component is changing.  I think this might be a bug in Material.  I've tried it without `ng-template` and `ngIf` on each `input`.  I also tried it with only one input.

Comment: Ok I think it might be because the ngIf is a structural directive and it might conflicting with the matInput. I've updated my answer with another example that will hopefully work.